# CentOS 6 producing an odd linking error

Tags: gcc, centos, scons, centos6

our network recently made the switch to CentOS 6 from CentOS 5. Upon compiling with gcc we find that at linking time we find this error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now it seemed that in CentOS5 that our compiler would bypass that.

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.a when searching for -lz
```

We are using a heavily modified SCons compiling tool (http://www.scons.org/). I can't figure out this bug and I have no idea where to start. The only difference in these errors is one machine is using centOS 5 and the other is using centOS6. Does anyone have any suggestions?

J

Comment: Typical problem is that the object files are for the wrong architecture. Try to unpack `/usr/lib/libz.a` and check the architecture with `file`

Answer (score 2):

> I can't figure out this bug and I have no idea where to start.

The problem is that you are building 64-bit program and the linker is finding 32-bit libz.a, or vice versa.

On your CentOS5 machine, the linker skips this incompatible `libz.a`, and finds another `libz.a` *somewhere else*.

On your CentOS6 machine, that somewhere else doesn't exist, so you get an error.

You can find out which `libz.a` the CentOS5 machine is using: add `-Wl,-t` flag to your link line and look at the output. Then find which package that `libz.a` belongs to, and install it on your CentOS6 machine.